# Recover bluetooth headset??

Tags: windows-7, windows

I just bought a bluetooth headset and used it for a day, and some minutes later my friend removed it from bluetooth devices and now i cant it there anymore. Anyone got an idea about how to recovery it?

Comment: **You will have to pair the device again**

Comment: What are you pairing it with? Your laptop? Computer?

Answer (score 1):

You have to unpair your headset resp. tell your headset to unpair.  Usually this is done by pressing some button on your headset, most probable for a few seconds.  Your headset's manual should tell you how to accomplish this.